# kendo tree view datasource does not bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Im passing a list from controller to view,my controller is:

```
 var myreslt = (from d in DB.MasterDatas
                       select new
                       {
                           categoryName = d.Country,
                           subCategories = d.City
                       }).ToList();
```

in the view im using kendo and want to show the above data in a tree view using the following code,but it only shows the name of the category(countries)and not the subset

```
  var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: result,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        children: "subCategories"
                    }
                }
            });


            $("#treeview-right").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: inline,

            });
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add a property which defines if an entry has children or not. Take a look into the documentation for HierarchicalDataSource: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/hierarchicaldatasource/overview

Comment: @CarstenFranke what should i add here?

Comment: `subCategories` property should contain an array but I suppose that in your example it contains just a city string. See an example here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/hierarchicaldatasource/configuration/schema#schemamodelchildren

Comment: See https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/hierarchicaldatasource/overview#binding-to-remote-data-services They have a property `HasEmployees` which is the configured column name for `hasChildren`.

Comment: @RomanKoliada yes but from linq how should pass such a thing?in my table i have two columns country and city

Comment: You have to create the right structure by yourself, kendo will not do it for you. I think you can use `.GroupBy` LINQ method.